# Let $S$ be the unit circle in the complex plane and $f :[0,2]\rightarrow S$ be defined as $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S$ be the unit circle in the complex plane with the induced topology from $\mathbb{C}$
and let $f :[0,2]\rightarrow S$ be defined as $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$

Then which of the following statements are true?

(a)  $K$ is closed in $[0,2] $ implies $ f(K) $ is closed in $S$.

(b)  $f(X)$ is closed in $S$ implies $ X$ is closed in $[0,2]$.

(c)  $U$ is open in $[0,2] $ implies $ f(U) $ is open in $S$.

(d)  $f(X)$ is open in $S$ implies $X$ is open in $[0,2]$.

My efforts:

As $f$ is a continuous map the inverse image of open/closed is open/closed so (d) and (b) are true.

What about other cases? I think they don't need to be true.

Comment: Actually, b) and d) are false and $a),c) are true!

Comment: Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Well, $f$ is a continuous map, but it is not bijective, so $f^{-1} (f(X))$ is not equal to $X$ for all open sets $X$ i.e. the inverse image of the set $f(X)$ is not $X$. You need to be more careful while tackling $b$ and $d$.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my first comment. c) is also false. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a) note that $f$ maps compact sets to compact sets. So a) is true. For b) use the fact that $f([0,1))=S$ but $[0,1)$ is not closed. For c) use that fact that $[0,\frac 1 2)$ is an open subsety of $[0,2]$ but $f([0,\frac 1 2))$is not open. Finally, $f((0,1])=S$ so d) is false.